# Script file size difference in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-10

I referenced `angular.min.js` file from google CDN at `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js` in my web page. When I opened the page in IE and look at the Network tab, it shows the file size is `104.16 KB` but when I open the same webpage in FireFox and look at the FireBug, it shows the file size is `38.3 KB`.

Is it because of the compression and gzip? If it is, how does it differ by browser?

Comment: chrome shows both compressed and uncompressed sizes if you have the detailed line toggle chosen, so you can compare your other browser sizes to that. if they don't match, then maybe  the script is injecting extra stuff for IE, but i wouldn't expect angular and a .js-named resource to to that...

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

If you save the text of the JavaScript file, the file size is 105KB (according to Windows).
Zipping the same file yields an archive of 39KB.

To answer your question for how it differs by browser, my copy of IE11 sends an `Accept-Encoding` header of `gzip/deflate`. If your browser isn't sending that header, then the server won't zip the response.

****Edit****

IE10 sends an `Accept-Encoding` header of `gizp/deflate` and receives a zipped stream, but reports only the uncompressed size.

Comment: In IE, in the "taken" column it shows it took 107ms for the file to download from google CDN and in FF it shows 50 ms. So if IE is receiving gzip version, why it is reporting time that is relevant to 105KB.

Comment: It is entirely possible that IE simply takes longer.